# GWT Firefox 31.0 PasswordTextBox width is longer than Textbox width

Tags: html, firefox, gwt

My Firefox version is 31.0, I set the GWT PasswordTextBox visible length as 20:

```
PasswordTextBox textBox = new PasswordTextBox();
textBox.setVisibleLength(20);
```

Same for textBox:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.setVisibleLength(20);
```

But the length of PasswordTextBox is a little longer than TextBox, how to make both have the same length?

No problem in Chrome, This problem is in Window Firefox 31.0, but no problem with firefox 26.0 in Linux.

[image]

Comment: Same problem in other browsers? My first impression, it's a margin/padding problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No problem in Chrome, This problem is in Window Firefox 31.0, no problem with firefox 26.0 in Linux.

Comment: Is there a margin or padding for the (Passwort)TextBox? Use firebug to find out.

Comment: Just did. No margin and padding for passwordtextbox. What I am guessing is that the  default font is different between textbox and passwordtextbox in GWT, but I am not sure.